# A better and faster way for eval?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I want to build my queries dynamically and use the following snippet:

```
--snip--
module.exports = {

get : function(req, res, next) {
  var queryStr = "req.database.table('locations').get(parseInt(req.params.id))";

  if (req.params.id) {
    if (req.fields) {
      queryStr += '.pick(' + req.fieldsStr + ')';
    }

    console.log(queryStr);
    eval(queryStr).run(function(result) { 
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    });
  } else if (!req.params.id) {
--snip--
```

However introducing eval opens up my code to injection (req.fields is filled with url parameters) and I see the response time of my app increase from 7 to 11ms

Is there a smarter way to accomplish what I did here?

Please advice.

Comment: This looks like it all boils down to needing to `eval` `req.fieldsStr`, and there is probably another way. What values could `req.fieldsStr` be?

Comment: fieldsStr is generated from an array, it contains string objects e.g. 'name', 'address', 'zipcode'

Comment: And I assume you have variables named `name`, `address`, `zipcode`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every ( or most ) injection the best solution is to have predefined list of possible fields. For example:

```
var predefined_fields = [ "id", "name", "age" ];

if (predefined_fields.indexOf( req.fieldsStr ) !== 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Also, you can push this: `parseInt(req.params.id)` outside of `queryStr`:

```
var id = parseInt(req.params.id);
var queryStr = "req.database.table('locations').get("+id+")";
```

which solves second injection issue.

Of course it might get a bit complicated in future, so I advice to write ( or use ) some kind of query generator.

I don't know the library you are using, but it looks, like you can simply do query without string concatenation and eval. After all this `.run` method stands for something, right? This will definetly improve performance and safety.

**EDIT** It seems that you don't need these strings at all. This should work:

```
var query = req.database.table('locations').get(parseInt(req.params.id));
if (req.params.id) {
    if (req.fields) {
      query = query.pick( req.fieldsStr );
    }

    console.log(queryStr);
    query.run(function(result) { 
       console.log(result);
       res.send(result);
    });
}
```

Safe and efficient. :)

Comment: the library is from rethinkdb, and I try to avoid modelling the data to take full advantage of the schemaless database

Comment: @user1707250 Yeah, so that's good. You don't need these strings. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you should go with something like the following:

```
--snip--
module.exports = {

get : function(req, res, next) {

  var queryResult = req.database.table('locations').get(parseInt(req.params.id));

  if (req.params.id) {
    if (req.fields) {
      queryResult = queryResult.pick.apply(queryResult, getFields(req.fieldsStr));
    }

    queryResult.run(function(result) { 
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    });
  } else if (!req.params.id) {
--snip--
```

where `getFields` is something like:

```
var fields = {
        'name': name,
        'address': address,
        'zipcode': zipcode
        // ...
    };

function getFields(str) {
    return str.split(',').map(function(u) {
        return fields[u];
    });
}
```

Of course, if `req.fields` is an array of strings itself, you could use that instead of splitting `req.fieldsStr`.